# Error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_cols()`: ! Can't recycle input of size 2 to size 1

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I have a dataframe and I want to simulate the change of wages over time, to simplify I'll give an example:

My data looks like this:

| agent | base_w | statu | wage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24104 | ACT |  |
| 2 | 3451 | n_ACT |  |
| 3 | 1567 | ACT |  |
| 4 | 45261 | n_ACT |  |

My lines of code are :

```
y <- 2 #years of simulation, 2 years to simplify.
# Create a list
evol <- list()
# Make "y" copies of your df
for (i in 1:y){evol[[i]] <- df}

# At each step (strting in the second element) evaluate the changes
for (i in 2:y) {
  # Logical vector (including the positions of rows to change)
   v.logic_ <- evol[[i-1]]$statu==ACT
  # Logical changes
   evol[[i]][v.logic_,"wage"] <- pmax(2500, evol[[i]][v.logic_ac,"base_w"]
}
```

But I end up with this error message:

```
Error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_cols()`:
! Can't recycle input of size 2 to size 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/vctrs_error_incompatible_size>
Error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_cols()`:
! Can't recycle input of size 2 to size 1.
```

Comment: The posted code does not run. `ACT` and `v.logic_ac` are undefined, and `pmax` doesn't have a closing `)`. It runs without error if I change `v.logic_ac` to `v.logic_` and `ACT` to `"ACT"`.